# jQuery addClass/removeClass while loading page using jinja template

Tags: jquery, html, css, flask, jinja2

I am trying to make a navigation bar, so that the currently active `<li>` tag stays highlighted with a different background color.

And once another option is clicked on the navigation bar, that `<li>` tag will be highlighted now, and not the previous one.

In the `.css` file:

```
.active {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

My `.js` code:

```
$(".topnav li").on('click', function() {
    $(".topnav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

For the page layout, i have created a `jinja` template named "comfylayout.html",

```
<title>
    {% block title %} {% endblock %}
</title>
<body>
        {% block body %} {% endblock %}
            <ol class='topnav'>
                <li><a href="{{url_for('decorators')}}">Decorators</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Turtle</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Tkinter</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Python regex</a></li>
            </ol>
</body>
```

It works fine for the last 3 `<li>` tags, where i am not loading any page, but when i click the first link, the `active` class is added, and quickly removed as soon as that page loads.

The loading page has content as below -

```
{% extends "comfylayout.html" %}
{% block title %}
    Decorators
{% endblock %}
{% block body %} ABC {% endblock %}
```

I am not very sure what I am missing here.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

When you click your link the target page gets loaded in your browser. So you won't see any effects of your Javascript code.

For my templates I use the following approach: Insert a small script at the beginning of each of your pages which sets the current button to active:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#decoratorBtn').addClass('active');
  })
```

You need to set the id of each button for this to work.